# How to add an external javascript file in Laravel-Admin

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-admin

I am stuck with a problem since yesterday with the use of Laravel Admin (https://laravel-admin.org/)

I would like to add a javascript script to be able to select all the elements of a multiSelect field.

1. I can not import the javascript file
2. how can I proceed (by javascript code) to select all the options of a field multiSelect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this

```
Admin::js("your path")
```